# Iterating with For Loop through Temporary Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to iterate over a Temporary Table inside of a Function, where I want to make an Update on every row.

The Temporary Table should hold all the user ID's that are getting out of the query.
After that, for every Single User it should be checked, if the percentage of the transactions with attributes is smaller than 50% of all transactions.

In the end, the account field master_segments should be updated.

My Code looks like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temptable()
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
BEGIN

  CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable AS
    SELECT account.sfid, transactions.transactionNumber
    FROM account
      INNER JOIN transactions ON account.sfid =transactions.accountsfid
      INNER JOIN transactionLineItems ON transactions.transactionNumber = transactionLineItems.transactionNumber
      INNER JOIN products ON transactionLineItems.USIM = products.USIM
        WHERE account.gender = '1' AND (transactions.transactionDate  >= current_date - interval '730' day AND products.gender = 'female' AND products.agegroup = 'adult'); 

    FOR j IN testTable.sfid LOOP
    SELECT(
          (SELECT COUNT(transactions.transactionNumber)
           FROM transactions
           INNER JOIN account ON account.sfid = transactions.accountsfid
           INNER JOIN transactionLineItems ON transactions.transactionNumber = transactionLineItems.transactionNumber
           INNER JOIN products ON transactionLineItems.USIM = products.USIM
           WHERE products.gender = 'male' AND products.agegroup = 'adult' AND transactions.transactionDate >= current_date - interval '730' day)*1.0 /
           (SELECT COUNT(transactions.transactionNumber)
           FROM transactions
           WHERE transactions.transactionDate >= current_date - interval '730' day)
         ) < 0.5;

         UPDATE account 
         SET account.master_segments = 'Women' WHERE account.sfid = testTable.sfid;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am getting this message:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "testTable"
LINE 14:     FOR j IN testTable.sfid LOOP`

Does someone has a suggestion on this?
Thanks!

Comment: please explain verbally what you try to achieve. your code seem to do lots of unnecessary and unclear things. eg - you dont need temp table to iterate over results. this is not how you iterate. second select is not saved in iny variable. update updates all rows to a constant... it's wronf on so many levels, that its hard to guess what you try to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you try to do is:

```
UPDATE account 
         SET account.master_segments = 'Women' 
FROM (
    SELECT account.sfid, transactions.transactionNumber
    FROM account
      INNER JOIN transactions ON account.sfid =transactions.accountsfid
      INNER JOIN transactionLineItems ON transactions.transactionNumber = transactionLineItems.transactionNumber
      INNER JOIN products ON transactionLineItems.USIM = products.USIM
        WHERE account.gender = '1' AND (transactions.transactionDate  >= current_date - interval '730' day AND products.gender = 'female' AND products.agegroup = 'adult')
) testtable
WHERE account.sfid = testtable.sfid
```

Comment: Here I am getting this Error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 18:     FROM (

line 18 is your line 4

Comment: This will probably still suffer from the *multiple updates per target row* syndrome (row versions). An `UPDATE account SET col='Female' WHERE EXISTS( ... stuff from transactions ... related to the same account ...)` will probably avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery and you don't need to repeat the `account` table for this logic:

```
UPDATE account a
     SET master_segments = 'Women' 
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     transactionLineItems tli
     ON t.transactionNumber = tli.transactionNumber AND
        t.transactionDate  >= current_date - interval '730' day INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON tli.USIM = p.USIM AND
        p.gender = 'female' AND
        p.agegroup = 'adult'
WHERE a.gender = '1' AND a.sfid = t.sfid;
```

I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.